# Ejecutar funcion de sumar y multiplicar al agregar una fila nueva a una tabla

Tags: javascript, html

tengo la siguiente tabla, en donde el usuario puede agregar una nueva fila, y dependiendo la cantidad de productos y su precio calcula un subtotal y sumando todos los subtotales, funciona solamente con la fila inicial, si agrego una fila nueva, no la toma en cuenta

[image: esta es mi tabla]

y estas son mis funciones

```
<script>
    // generamos un evento click y keyup para cada elemento input con la clase .input
    var input=document.querySelectorAll(".input");
    input.forEach(function(e) {
        e.addEventListener("click",multiplica);
        e.addEventListener("keyup",multiplica);
    });

    // funcion que genera la multiplicacion
    function multiplica() {

        // nos posicionamos en el tr del producto
        var tr=this.closest("tr");

        var total=1;

        // recorremos todos los elementos del tr que tienen la clase .input
        var inputs=tr.querySelectorAll(".input");
        inputs.forEach(function(e) {
            total*=e.value;
        });

        // mostramos el total con dos decimales
        tr.querySelector(".total").value=total.toFixed(2);

        // indicamos que calcule el total
        calcularTotal(this.closest("table"));
    }

    // funcion que calcula la suma total de los productos
    function calcularTotal(e) {
        var total=0;

        // obtenemos todos los totales y los sumamos
        var totales=e.querySelectorAll(".total");
        totales.forEach(function(e) {
            total+=parseFloat(e.value);
        });

        // mostramos la suma total con dos decimales
        e.getElementsByClassName("totales")[0].value=total.toFixed(2);
    }



     function agregarFila(){
                document.getElementById("tablaprueba").insertRow(1).innerHTML = '<td><input type="text" required></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="number" class="monto input" min="0"></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="number" class="monto input" min="0"></td>' +
                    '<td> <input type="text" class="monto total" value="0" disabled></td>';
            }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando lanzas el código con el que enlazas la función `multiplica()` a los `.input`, los que se generan con la función `agregarFila()`, no se encuentran en el **DOM** por lo que no la reciben.

Para solucionarlo podrías dentro de la función `agregarFila()` vincularles el evento a esos nuevos `.input`.

```js
function agregarFila(){
    document.getElementById("tablaprueba").insertRow(1).innerHTML = '<td><input type="text" required></td>' +
        '<td><input type="number" class="monto input" min="0"></td>' +
        '<td><input type="number" class="monto input" min="0"></td>' +
        '<td> <input type="text" class="monto total" value="0" disabled></td>';
        
      //Accedemos a los .input de la última fila (que es la que se acaba de crear)
      let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#tablaprueba tr:last-child .input');
      
      //Los recorremos para añadirles los eventos que necesitamos.
      inputs.forEach(function (input) {
        input.addEventListener("click",multiplica);
        input.addEventListener("keyup",multiplica);
      });
}
```